# fortran: how to get the node name of a cluster

Tags: linux, fortran

I am running a fortran code on a cluster equiped with linux system. When the code begin to run, I want it to output some basic information of the node where it is running, especially the node name. How to do it in fortran.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your code is parallelised with MPI - which is kind of common for a code running on a cluster - then just call `MPI_Get_processor_name()` that just does exactly this.
If not, just use the `iso_c_binding` module to call the C function `gethostname()`, which again just does that.

**EDIT**: here is an example on how to call `gethostname()` with the `iso_c_binding` module. I'm definitely not an expert with that so it might not be the most effective one ever...

```
module unistd
  interface
    integer( kind = C_INT ) function gethostname( hname, len ) bind( C, name = 'gethostname' )
        use iso_c_binding
        implicit none
        character( kind = C_CHAR ) :: hname( * )
        integer( kind = C_INT ), VALUE :: len
    end function gethostname
  end interface
end module unistd

program hostname
    use iso_c_binding
    use unistd
    implicit none
    integer( kind = C_INT ), parameter :: sl = 100
    character( kind = C_CHAR ) :: hn( sl )
    character( len = sl ) :: fn
    character :: c
    integer :: res, i, j

    res = gethostname( hn, sl )
    if ( res == 0 ) then 
        do i = 1, sl
            c = hn( i )
            if ( c == char( 0 ) ) exit
            fn( i: i ) = c
        end do
        do j = i, sl
            fn( j: j ) = ' '
        end do
        print *, "->", trim( fn ), "<-"
    else
        print *, "call to gethostname() didn't work..."
    end if
end program hostname
```

Comment: Hi, Gilles. Thank you for answer. I can confirm `MPI_Get_processor_name()` works. But I am unable to get `gethostname()` to work, could you please give a code example on this?

Comment: Oh, my god. It is really out of my expectation. I thought it must be a few lines... Anyway, as I tested, this works! I think I'd stick with MPI approach, or RussF's method is also very good.

Answer (score 4):

If the information you want is contained in an environment variable the easy way is just to get its value from a call to `get_environment_variable`. For the hostname

```
program gethost
character*32 hostname
call get_environment_variable('HOST',hostname)
write(*,*) 'My gracious host is ',trim(hostname)
end program gethost
```

Comment: This works. On my cluster, the environment variable is `HOSTNAME`. Thank you so much