# Using GDB to debug an MPI program in Fortran (on MAC)

Tags: debugging, emacs, fortran, gdb, mpi

I was using the answer from this post ([Using GDB to debug an MPI program in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38699238/using-gdb-to-debug-an-mpi-program-in-fortran)) to debug an MPI Fortran program on my Mac. I tried to implement the answer that was given by Vladimir F. However, after:

```
gdb -pid <the_pid_you_got_from_getpid>
```

The debugger opened and I got the following message:

```
warning: unhandled dyld version (15)

0x00007fffb6f2ef46 in ?? ()

And when I tried:

(gdb) info locals
```

I got `"No symbol table info available"`. As a result I can not attach gdb to the running process.

I am working with MacOS 10.12 (Sierra), gdb 8.0, and compiling with mpif90 configured for ifort (version: 17.0.4).

Any ideas about what could be the cause of my problem?

Comment: Please show how you compile your code. You *must* tell the compiler to generate debugging symbols by `-g`. In addition, there are multiple different formats of dynamic libraries and debugging symbols and gdb may not support your current setting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I compiled using mpif90 -ggdb test.f90 and then I ran using mpirun -n 2 ./a.out.

Comment: Also I tried mpif90 -g main.f90. It did not work as well.

Comment: What about a simple serial program compiled dirextly by ifort?

Comment: I can compile it and debug it without a problem.

Comment: what if you `gdb <exe> <pid>` instead ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are not that committed to gdb (which is, in fact, deprecated at mac os as part of default toolchain), you can play with lldb.

So, for a code like this:

```
program main

  use mpi

  integer error
  integer id
  integer p
  call MPI_Init ( error )
  call MPI_Comm_size ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, p, error )
  call MPI_Comm_rank ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, id, error )
  write (*,*) 'Hello: ', id, '/', p
  call MPI_Finalize ( error )
  stop
end
```

and compilation like this

```
mpif90 -g -o fort ./fort.f90
```

you should be able to start lldb following way

```
mpirun -np 2 xterm -e lldb ./fort
```

which will give you two, separate xterms with lldb running

[image]

Note that for xterm you need to have XQuartz installed (https://www.xquartz.org)

**Update:**

I am not sure whether this will help with this particular issue, but you can always try to compile GDB from the sources. Take a look here for description how to do it: [Building GDB on macOS Sierra](http://www.owsiak.org/?p=3689)

Then, you can run mpirun with xterm and gdb and your MPI code like this

```
mpirun -np 2 xterm -e gdb ./mpi_sample
```

Now, you can see that there is still warning with dyld version, but code seems to work fine.

[image]

But still, question is, what will happen with ifort compiled code :( In my case I am using:

```
mpifort --version
GNU Fortran (GCC) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

gdb --version
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

mpirun --version
mpirun (Open MPI) 2.0.2
```

Comment: You can use `(lldb) process attach --pid 123` or
 `(lldb) attach -p 123 ` to achieve similar functionality to that one linked in the question.

Comment: Have you confirmed lldb supports Intel Fortran?

Comment: I don't have ifort compiler :( Can't say anything about that :( Still, I guess it's worth at least a try.

Comment: Yes it is. It looks like there the OP has some incompatibility between the debugger and some library. A different debugger could fix it.